# Are there names for function which doesn't have all items in it's domain as defined?

Tags: functions

[image]

Consider a function similar to the one above where except for a few points in the domain, the function is bijective. Is there a name given for this kind of function similar to bijectivity?

My initial guess was discontinuous functions but I'm not sure how well that concept works for discrete functions.

Comment: I think that the term is "not a function".  Continuity is a very different matter.

Comment: Reason I thought that is because of functions like $ \frac{1}{x-a}$, at x=a it is not really defined and hence we call discontinous

Comment: By definition of domain, a function value is defined for all points in its domain. Any points for which it is not defined are not part of its domain. So it is a bijective function, whose domain is a subset of whatever set you started with.

Comment: In casual speech maybe but not formally.  This is a function on $\mathbb{R} - \{a\}$ and it would be continuous on that restricted domain.  It could be extended to all of $\mathbb{R}$ by defining an arbitrary value at $a$, in that case, it would be discontinuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A discontinuous function is still defined on every point in its domain, discontinuity is defined in terms of limits. What you’re describing is called a ‘[partial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function)’, I believe the term sees some use in computer science, but you’re unlikely to find it in a standard mathematics course.